# virtual machine connection

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I want to connect ubuntu virtual boxes with each other on a network. I want to use hadoop on it. So i need to put them in a network. It requires **ssh** to communicate. Can anyone help regarding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to change your adapter to "Bridged networking" instead of "Nat", the default. This way the guest system will get an ip on your local network and you can connect directly to it.